# Why do I get a "non-static member function" error when passing a function as a parameter to a pthread in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I am at a loss for what to do with this. When I try to compile the code, using threads, it gives me the following errors at the bottom of my post. Mainly, something like: "test-10-21-2016.cpp:62:61: error: invalid use of non-static member function"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

#include<thread>

#include<sstream>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cctype>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include <ctime>
//
//#include<atomic>
//
#include <unistd.h>
#include<time.h>

#include"Directory.hpp"
#include"Tests.hpp"
//#define NUM_THREADS 2

using namespace std;


int main() {
    Emotions e;
    DictObj d;
    //Time t;
    //User u;
    Self s;
    Tests test;
    vector < thread > threads;




    Emotions temp;

    //pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    //-----------------------------------------------
    e.setEmo(50, 50, 25, 50, 40, 50, 30, 20, 10, 20);
    temp.setEmo(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

    s.setEmotions(e);
    s.setTempEmo(temp);


    /*
    int rc;
    int tc;
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, s.tempEmotions, s, e, temp, 200);
    tc = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, test.testEmoALL, NULL);
    */
    //----------------------------------------------
    threads.push_back(thread(s.tempEmotions,s,e,temp,200));
    thread first(s.tempEmotions, s, e, temp, 200);
    thread second(test.testEmoALL);
    first.join();
    second.join();

    cout << endl << "First and second completed";


    first.detach();
    second.detach();
    //----------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

**ERRORS:**

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c "test-10-21-2016.cpp" -lpthread (in directory: /home/courtneymaroney/Desktop/Courtney/Documents/AI/NEW)
test-10-21-2016.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test-10-21-2016.cpp:62:61: error: invalid use of non-static member function
  threads.push_back(thread(static_cast<Self*>(s.tempEmotions,s,e,temp,200));
                                                             ^
test-10-21-2016.cpp:63:46: error: invalid use of non-static member function
  thread first(s.tempEmotions, s, e, temp, 200);
                                              ^
test-10-21-2016.cpp:64:31: error: invalid use of non-static member function
  thread second(test.testEmoALL);
                               ^
Compilation failed.
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Thanks.

For whatever reason, if I create a class within this .cpp file and pass class like so, 
`thread first(&RunF::function1, ref(f));` 
where "f" is `RunF f;` and RunF is a class defined as:

```
    #include<thread>
    class RunF {
        private:
            Emotions e;
            DictObj d;
            Self s;
            Tests test;
            Emotions temp;
       public:
            void setE(Emotions emo) {e = emo;}
            void setTE(Emotions emo) {temp = emo;}
            void setS(Self emo) {s= emo;}
            void setT(Tests emo) {test = emo;}
            void setD(DictObj emo) { d = emo;}
            //----------------------
            void function0() { test.testEmoALL(); }
            void function1() {
            s.tempEmotions(200, e, temp, s);
         }
    };
```

The multithreading will function properly. (Note: I am using `thread` here instead of `pthread`.)

I am not quite sure why this is, and why I cannot just import a class and use the classes functions. I am also not sure why I must use an empty function rather than one with parameters.

Comment: Unrelated to the compiler error, but why are you calling `detach()` after `join()`ing the threads? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You need to form a pointer-to-member:

```
thread(&Self::tempEmotions, s, e, temp, 200)
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Pointers-to-member, not to be confused with "pointers to a member", are properties of a class, not of an object. They don't point at object members, but instead at class members in the abstract sense. You can only make use of a pointer-to-member together with an object instance (which you provide in the next argument, `s`).

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting other problems

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c "test-10-21-2016.cpp" -lpthread (in directory: /home/courtneymaroney/Desktop/Courtney/Documents/AI/NEW)
test-10-21-2016.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test-10-21-2016.cpp:64:31: error: invalid use of non-static member function
  thread second(test.testEmoALL);
                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:39:0,
                 from test-10-21-2016.cpp:7:`

Comment: `/usr/include/c++/5/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_check_arity<void (Self::*)(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int), Self&, Emotions&, Emotions&, int>’:
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1538:12:   required from ‘struct std::_Bind_simple_helper<void (Self::*)(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int), Self&, Emotions&, Emotions&, int>’`

Comment: @CourtneyMaroney: 1) understand the underlying principle of the problem exemplified by the answer, 2) apply it wherever it applies.

Comment: `
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1552:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> typename std::_Bind_simple_helper<_Func, _BoundArgs>::__type std::__bind_simple(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Self::*)(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int); _Args = {Self&, Emotions&, Emotions&, int}]’
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:137:59:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Self::*)(Self, Emotions, Emotions, int); _Args = {Self&, Emotions&, Emotions&, int}]’`

Comment: If this answer fixed the problem, then you should accept it. If you think it's wrong, then don't. If you have to fix the same error in multiple places, you can do so now thanks to someone providing the knowledge, for which they should get the credit. If there are other, unrelated errors, they can go in a new question.